Duties when bringing Canadian goods to US in luggage
If a US citizen visits Canada for a day or two, and buys goods made in Canada that are worth more than the duty-free limit, can those goods be brought back to the US for free, since Canadian-made goods can be imported tariff free? I'm excluding alcoholic beverages and tobacco, since they have their own tax scheme.

There is a difference between importing goods as part of a business and bringing them back for your own use.

Assume it's for my own use, and an amount an individual is likely to bring back for him/herself.

Free trade agreements apply to goods being imported for reselling (or for use in manufacturing something else). They do not apply to imports of goods for personal use. Just because there is a free trade agreement with Canada that doesn't mean you can import your personal items for free.
The very fact that the law has a 'duty free" limit, above which taxes have to be paid, should indicate this.
As littleadv says, declare your goods and the customs guard will tell you what you need to pay.

The logic is pretty flawed here. The EU internal free trade agreement definitely cover personal use, and there's still a duty-free limit for the EU. You need to consider the actual provisions of the applicable free trade agreement. Now I don't know what the US-Canada agreement says, so I don't know if the conclusion is correct.

@MSalters the EU doesn't have an internal free trade agreement; it is a customs union.  This is why there are customs controls between the EU and EFTA countries, for example, but not between EU countries.  The duty free limit does not apply for travel between EU countries except for excise goods such as alcohol and tobacco, which are explicitly given different treatment in EU law.

This answer is incorrect; see Spehro 'speff' Pefhany's answer.

What counts is the actual country of origin. If the goods were made in some other country than Canada or Mexico then other rules may apply when you exceed the duty free amount.
There are many, many rules (a thick book) and some goods are subject to limits or outright bans for various reasons, or crazy high tariffs.
If the amounts are significant, I suggest researching the anticipated amounts that could be due. You may be able to get a good answer with a phone call. To pick an extreme case, the tariff on a Chinese-made EV brought from Canada to the US could be 100%, even if it is a Tesla brand and all Canadian taxes have been paid.
Fortunately, the US, unlike Canada, does not impose a federal sales tax, nor do the feds collect tax on behalf of states.
Here is a simplified overview from CBP aimed at the layman traveler. There are basically 3 categories by value, exempt, subject to simplified rules if less than $1,800 value and originating in certain countries, and those subject to the full panoply of rules. In practice there is some flexibility in the values but I would not expect that  to extend to many thousands of dollars.
In the particular case of goods exceeding the duty-free maximum being brought from Canada, the cbp website is clear that country of origin should be considered:

If you are returning from Canada or Mexico, your goods are eligible
for free or reduced duty rates if they were grown, manufactured, or
produced in Canada or Mexico, as defined by the Act.

Generally speaking (ignoring garment quotas, for example), the rules for personal imports are as favorable or more favorable than those for commercial imports, so if the goods qualify as North American origin under the US law they will be duty free.

For personal items bought in a retail store I don't think that's true. Customs will not care where the things you bring in for yourself were made, or even where they were bought. The only notable exception is Cuban tobacco products.

@DJClayworth See above.

You'll need to declare them, and the CBP will determine the duties to be paid. The CBP is well-aware of the trade agreements they're enforcing. Note that the penalty for failing to declare may be more than any tariff (or lack thereof).
